# gradlew bootRun vs java -jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got into a situation where running

`./gradlew bootRun`

gives me a successful run but if I try:

`./gradlew bootJar && java -jar ./build/libs/xxxx.jar` I get errors

It launches the jar each time but I'm assuming `bootRun` is adding some set of extra params/env/properties etc.

Is there a way to figure out what ever the "extra stuff" bootRun is doing in order to make it so that I can call `java -jar` with the same env?

Thanks

### Actual Errors

I'm getting some wacky errors (see below) that I was only getting under the `java -jar` condition in some cases .. sometimes it was both - so I was trying to figure out the differences

```
2021-05-23 11:37:23.725  INFO 21111 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-23 11:37:23.735  INFO 21111 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-23 11:37:23.735  INFO 21111 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-23 11:37:23.798  INFO 21111 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-23 11:37:23.799  INFO 21111 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1713 ms
2021-05-23 11:37:24.184  INFO 21111 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
2021-05-23 11:37:24.185  INFO 21111 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2021-05-23 11:37:24.349  WARN 21111 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/http/converter/json/KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter.<init>()V @4: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0001 b700 02b1

2021-05-23 11:37:24.350  INFO 21111 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
2021-05-23 11:37:24.353  INFO 21111 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-05-23 11:37:24.369  INFO 21111 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-23 11:37:24.386 ERROR 21111 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/http/converter/json/KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter.<init>()V @4: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0001 b700 02b1

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.mitre.abcd.tmi.translator.TmiTranslatorApplication$Companion.main(TmiTranslatorApplication.kt:36) ~[main/:na]
        at org.mitre.abcd.tmi.translator.TmiTranslatorApplication.main(TmiTranslatorApplication.kt) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/http/converter/json/KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter.<init>()V @4: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0001 b700 02b1

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/http/converter/json/KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter.<init>()V @4: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0001 b700 02b1

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2021) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2032) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.configureMessageConverters(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:216) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.configureMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:137) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.configureMessageConverters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:863) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:671) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:369) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/http/converter/json/KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter.<init>()V @4: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0001 b700 02b1

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/http/converter/json/KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter.<init>()V @4: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'kotlinx/serialization/json/Json$Default' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0001 b700 02b1

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:933) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:865) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters$1.defaultMessageConverters(HttpMessageConverters.java:175) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters.getDefaultConverters(HttpMessageConverters.java:178) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters.<init>(HttpMessageConverters.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters.<init>(HttpMessageConverters.java:89) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.messageConverters(HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.java:70) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What errors do you get with `java -jar`?

Comment: Also, aren't you getting the final cmdline string in the console? Post your `build.gradle`, we'll try to help

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens when you have a mismatch of versions of kotlinx-serialization (and also possibly main kotlin) in your project vs your dependencies. Verify with `gradle depencencies` etc., and bump the versions to the newest whenever possible. It fixed the problem for me.